# Why is assuming Determinacy the same as Independence?

Tags: regression, probability, independence

Consider a standard linear model

$$y =  x\beta_0 + \epsilon$$ or perhaps more generally a non-linear model

$$ y = h(x,\beta) + \epsilon$$

I have several times come across the phrase that: To treat $x$ as determined (non-stochastic) is equivalent to the assumption that the error $\epsilon$ and covariates $x$ are independent.

Why is this the case?

I am not necessarily asking for a deep proof if one exists, but I am interested in hearing how someone with more insight in probability theory would convey the intuition of the claim and perhaps illustrate with simple examples.

Comment: Are you interested in the context of linear models or regression? If so, consider adding the relevant tags.